# arduino loop error on concatenation

Tags: arduino-uno

I am new to arduino, and a bit stuck on some arduino logics.
I am creating an arduino to show a status webpage using the arduino ethernet shield.

The setup: Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

this first seems logic:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
{
  client.println("Line :");
  client.println(i);
  client.println("<br>");
}
```

it will output this, as expacted

```
Line : 0 
Line : 1 
Line : 2 
Line : 3 
Line : 4 
Line : 5 
Line : 6 
Line : 7 
Line : 8 
Line : 9
```

now if I want to concatenate **"Line :"** and **i** inside the code

my code will be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
{
  client.println("Line :" + i);
  client.println("<br>");
}
```

I would expect to see the same output as above, but in fact, I see:

```
Line : 
ine : 
ne : 
e : 
: 
:
```

I never do a substring or other string function to remove the first characters on each line, so how is arduino handling this?

a second question, so when I concatenate everything in my code like this:

```
client.println("Line :" + i + "<br>");
```

I have this error:

```
exit status 1
invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [5]' to binary 'operator+'
```

I suppose, the "+" operator is the concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino `Serial.print()` does not support concatenation in it's regular form you are using. You  got two options :

1- Use multiple `Serial.print()` commands one after each other as you have already tried.

2- Use "Streaming" library for Arduino. The syntax would be something like that in your case:

```
Serial << "Line" << i << "<br>" << endl;
```

For more info check this link out :
http://arduiniana.org/libraries/streaming/